# Hyperloop - Tokbox - iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, opentok, tokbox, appcelerator-hyperloop

i need to develop an app (iOS) with videoconference, there is a lib called TokBox, but works only with xcode ( i mean, native code ), so i am wondering if hyperloop can handle it.

I will use classic development and  SDK 5.2.2 GA

Thanks in advance.

[Tokbox lib](https://tokbox.com)

Answer (score 1):

I see Tokbox is [available as Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=tokbox), which is the easiest way to include iOS stuff in Hyperloop projects. The [Hyperloop Example App](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/blob/master/Podfile) also demonstrates this.

Comment: Thanks.. i will take a look